# How to only change the <p> tag that inside the <ul> tag without having to modify HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble to make the p tag that inside of the ul tag to not have the same css modification and all the p tags not inside the ul tag.

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style-type: circle;
  margin-left: 10px
}

p {
  margin-top: 0.2px;
  margin-bottom: 0.2px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <p>values is the world of hurt</p>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p><abbr title="Internet Message Access Protocol">IMAP</abbr> is used to fetch mail from the server so you can read it in clients like Thunderbird or on your phone.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p><abbr title="Post Office Protocol">POP</abbr> is an older protocol that does the same job as IMAP, but is less flexible.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>The <abbr title="Simple Mail Transfer Protocol">SMTP</abbr> protocol is used to send email, either from a client program you are using, or from one mail server to another. SMTP has existed since the 1980s, but has been extended several times to
        add user authentication, encryption, and other features.</p>
      <p>SMTP is where most spam fighting happens: preventing fraudulent email from being sent the ultimate goal.</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without modifying the html or adding classes, you could target all `p` tags that are `not` inside a `ul`, like so:

```
p:not(ul p) {
    margin-top: 0.2px;
    margin-bottom: 0.2px;
}
```

Full working example: (Run code snippet)

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style-type: circle;
  margin-left: 10px
}

p:not(ul p) {
  margin-top: 0.2px;
  margin-bottom: 0.2px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <p>values is the world of hurt</p>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p><abbr title="Internet Message Access Protocol">IMAP</abbr> is used to fetch mail from the server so you can read it in clients like Thunderbird or on your phone.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p><abbr title="Post Office Protocol">POP</abbr> is an older protocol that does the same job as IMAP, but is less flexible.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>The <abbr title="Simple Mail Transfer Protocol">SMTP</abbr> protocol is used to send email, either from a client program you are using, or from one mail server to another. SMTP has existed since the 1980s, but has been extended several times to
        add user authentication, encryption, and other features.</p>
      <p>SMTP is where most spam fighting happens: preventing fraudulent email from being sent the the ultimate goal.</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
<html>
```

> As stated from @Temani Afif in the comments, the solution above has not been implemented in all browsers yet and as of this date, is only working in Safari. (It is in 'Working Draft').

Another solution could be to use the `!important` flag to override the margins of all `p` tags that are within `ul`'s, like so:

```
ul p {
    margin: 1em 0 !important;
}
```

```css
p {
  margin-top: 0.2px;
  margin-bottom: 0.2px;
}

ul p {
   margin: 1em 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <p>values is the world of hurt</p>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p><abbr title="Internet Message Access Protocol">IMAP</abbr> is used to fetch mail from the server so you can read it in clients like Thunderbird or on your phone.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p><abbr title="Post Office Protocol">POP</abbr> is an older protocol that does the same job as IMAP, but is less flexible.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>The <abbr title="Simple Mail Transfer Protocol">SMTP</abbr> protocol is used to send email, either from a client program you are using, or from one mail server to another. SMTP has existed since the 1980s, but has been extended several times to
        add user authentication, encryption, and other features.</p>
      <p>SMTP is where most spam fighting happens: preventing fraudulent email from being sent the the ultimate goal.</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: You can use classnames with which you can limit the CSS to be applied for specific `p` tags under selected lists.

Comment: @NiteshPhadatare, Yes, true, that would be best if you wanted to target p tags only in a specific list. However not if you wanted to target all `p` tags in all unordered lists.

Comment: Yes agree @Bryan Elliott

Comment: note that your snippet will only work on Safari and not on the other browser

Comment: @TemaniAfif, yes it does work, if you inspect the `p` tags inside the unordered list, you'll see it doesn't have any user defined `margin` styles applied to it..  However when you look at it, it appears like it has margin's because of the default margin's that are automatically inherited default by the browser. I included this fact in my answer. I've tested it in chrome, firefox, and edge, and all working as expected.

Comment: no, you can inspect the elements and you will see that you CSS is not applied to any `p`. `:not()` doesn't yet support complex selector, only Safari support this

Answer (score 1):

According to the question you have a static defined HTML structure that you can't change - add classes for example.

- Use `:not(li) > p` to limit the rule to items that don't have list item as their parent. If you've got `li > div > p` the rule will be applied to them.

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style-type: circle;
  margin-left: 10px
}

:not(li) > p {
  margin-top: 0.2px;
  margin-bottom: 0.2px;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <p>values is the world of hurt</p>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p><abbr title="Internet Message Access Protocol">IMAP</abbr> is used to fetch mail from the server so you can read it in clients like Thunderbird or on your phone.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p><abbr title="Post Office Protocol">POP</abbr> is an older protocol that does the same job as IMAP, but is less flexible.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>The <abbr title="Simple Mail Transfer Protocol">SMTP</abbr> protocol is used to send email, either from a client program you are using, or from one mail server to another. SMTP has existed since the 1980s, but has been extended several times to
        add user authentication, encryption, and other features.</p>
      <p>SMTP is where most spam fighting happens: preventing fraudulent email from being sent the the ultimate goal.</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
<html>
```

- A naive solution - apply the style rules only to a `p` element which is a direct descendant of the `body` - `body > p`. This will not effect any `p` which is not a direct descent, so a `p` under a `div` would be ignored as well.

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style-type: circle;
  margin-left: 10px
}

body > p {
  margin-top: 0.2px;
  margin-bottom: 0.2px;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <p>values is the world of hurt</p>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p><abbr title="Internet Message Access Protocol">IMAP</abbr> is used to fetch mail from the server so you can read it in clients like Thunderbird or on your phone.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p><abbr title="Post Office Protocol">POP</abbr> is an older protocol that does the same job as IMAP, but is less flexible.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>The <abbr title="Simple Mail Transfer Protocol">SMTP</abbr> protocol is used to send email, either from a client program you are using, or from one mail server to another. SMTP has existed since the 1980s, but has been extended several times to
        add user authentication, encryption, and other features.</p>
      <p>SMTP is where most spam fighting happens: preventing fraudulent email from being sent the the ultimate goal.</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: This might go wrong if there is any `p` tag comes under `div` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use class name as `list-para` for all `p` tags inside `ul` and then use following CSS.

```
p:not(.list-para) {
    margin-top: 0.2px;
    margin-bottom: 0.2px;
    color: red;
}
```

**Detail Answer**

You can give a class name to all the `p` tags inside `ul` and use CSS selector with `:not` as shown below. I have added a text color as red just for differentiation.

This will work for all the p tags which doesn't fall under the `ul` tag which you don't want the CSS to be applied.

Also if there are two `ul` lists in your DOM then you can allow `p` tag under other `ul` tag to apply this CSS.

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style-type: circle;
  margin-left: 10px
}

p:not(.list-para) {
  margin-top: 0.2px;
  margin-bottom: 0.2px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <p>values is the world of hurt</p>
  <ul class="list">
    <li>
      <p class="list-para"><abbr title="Internet Message Access Protocol">IMAP</abbr> is used to fetch mail from the server so you can read it in clients like Thunderbird or on your phone.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p class="list-para"><abbr title="Post Office Protocol">POP</abbr> is an older protocol that does the same job as IMAP, but is less flexible.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p class="list-para">The <abbr title="Simple Mail Transfer Protocol">SMTP</abbr> protocol is used to send email, either from a client program you are using, or from one mail server to another. SMTP has existed since the 1980s, but has been extended several times to
        add user authentication, encryption, and other features.</p>
      <p class="list-para">SMTP is where most spam fighting happens: preventing fraudulent email from being sent the the ultimate goal.</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
<html>
```